# Есть ли такое значение у приставки "у"

Tags: приставка

Какое же значение у приставки "у" в слове "***упустить***"? Я никакого не смогла подобрать.

Для меня "упустить" - это *"случайно, ненамеренно что-то потерять"*, но такого значения я не нашла. Конкретно здесь как: сделать не по своей воле что-то. Как же может слово тогда быть связано с "пустить", где всегда "воля своя": запустить, отпустить, впустить, напустить, распустить).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Промчались, пролетели эти годы,
 Пора неповторимая, когда
 То белые мне снились пароходы,
 То быстрые, как ветер поезда.

 Несбывшихся снов чуть слышное эхо
 Опять мне уснуть не дает,
 Но поезд уехал, мой поезд уехал,
 Уплыл без меня пароход.

 Наверно, это вновь судьба смеется,
 Но в этот раз меня не проведет!
 Я знаю, что мой поезд не вернется,
 И белый пароход не приплывет.
```

Песня Маши Звездной https://yandex.ru/video/preview/11937454086253929711

1. Уехал, уплыл, и это **навсегда**: действие окончено, продолжения не будет. У каждой приставки есть свое **центральное** значение, и в в данном случае это значение **полной завершенности** как точки невозврата.

Даже **звук У** к этому располагает. Есть в нем какое-то **уныние и разочарование**, так выглядят несбывшиеся надежды. И еще так воют волки, будто жалуются на что.

2. А теперь нужно определить **частное** значение **[приставки У](https://gufo.me/dict/kuznetsov/%D1%83_8b7)** в слове "упустить".

Больше походит **первое значение:**  1. Обозначает: направленность действия, движения  от чего-л., удаление, устранение, исчезновение чего-л. **Улететь, ускакать, утечь.**

**ПУСКАТЬ**, несов. (сов. пустить), кого-что. Отпускать (отпустить) кого-л., **перестав удерживать силой,** дав кому-, чему-л. **свободу**;

**УПУСТИТЬ**, упущу, упустишь; упущенный; -щен, -а, -о; св. кого-что. 1. Не удержав, выпустить из рук; уронить. У. верёвку. У. весло. У. из рук. 2. Не сумев удержать, **дать возможность уйти,** убежать, уплыть и т.п.  У. птицу. У. бревно. У. рыбу. У. зайца.

**ДИАЛОГ**

— Давай кораблики в озере **пускать**.

— Давай!  Я уже свой кораблик **пустил**, пусть плывет, куда хочет.

— Ты его не только пустил, но и **упустил**. Теперь нам его из воды не достать.

Answer (score 0):

У глагола "упустить" пять значений, см.:

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Нигде нет привязки к "сделать не по своей воле что-то". Однако эти пять значений не исключают (молча), что все пять "у" могут произойти не по своей воле.